# Randomly sort php array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting an array of 25 items from a database using SQL. I want to take 16 of the items and random to use. I thought if I could randomly sort the array I could then take the first 16 items.

Is there a way to randomly sort an array in php, or perform an SQL SELECT that returns to results in a random order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in SQL:

```
<your select here>
order by rand()
limit 16;
```